# Google Sheets' IMPORTDATA randomly converts number

Tags: google-sheets, importdata

We have a simple REST endpoint that returns a number as a string. The number is rounded to two decimals and has a point, like this: `2385.1`
Google Sheets then sometimes transforms this into `177418` or some other nonsensical value.
The endpoint has Content-Type set to to `test/csv` but we've also tried `text/plain` with the same effect. Changing the format of the cell didn't fix the problem.
Any ideas how we can get Google Sheets to represent the number consistently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that Google Sheets sometimes thinks that `2385.1` is a date as `177418` is the serial number for `2385-10-01 00:00:00`.

You could try changing the spreadsheet locale (File > Settings > Locale).

Another option is to use the URL Fetch Service from Google Apps Script to read the value from your REST endpoint. One way to use is to create a custom function to be used in the same way that IMPORTDATA, but you will have control about how the value is wrote to Google Sheets.

Comment: The locale setting lead me down the right path. If it's one where numbers use a comma for the decimal point then it will wrongly parse certain numbers. If I send a CSV file (with commas as delimiter) it's going to split numbers. The solution was to change the locale to one which uses dots.